# ServiceStack: Confused about routes

Tags: silverlight, servicestack

I am starting to look into ServiceStack and possibility of replacing RiaServices with ServiceStack based approach. We already use one Dto per View anyway and use NH on the backend. I modified webconfig by adding a  element to point to "api" instead of the root of the application (Silverlight), created service, defined the route etc. I can hit localhost:12543/api/metadata and I get the operation listed. When I click on the operation it gives me available route for the operation "api/certificates". If I use rest client plugin for firefox, I can hit `http://localhost:12543/api/json/reply/CertificateDefinitionList`  and I get expected data. But, if I do `http://localhost:12543/api/certificates` I get 404 error, and in fiddler it says that "Handler for the request not found". What am I missing?

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Thu, 21 Mar 2013 19:44:07 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/3.942 Win32NT/.NET
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1316
Connection: Close

Handler for Request not found: 


Request.ApplicationPath: /
Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath: /api/certificates
Request.FilePath: /api/certificates
Request.HttpMethod: GET
```

In Web.config

```
  <!-- service stack hosting at custom path-->
  <location path="api">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
      </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
    <!-- Required for IIS 7.0 -->
    <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      <handlers>
        <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

Global.asax

```
public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
{
   //this is because ria entry for system.webserver makes it not work for 
   // service stack
   SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig
   {
      ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath = "api",
   });

   container.RegisterAutoWired<ComplianceService>();

   Routes.Add<CertificateDefinitionList>("/api/certificates");
}
```

Comment: What custom routes have you defined? i,e. Have you defined one for `/certificates` ?

Comment: My "error" was in Global.asax as I was defining the route as /api/certificates, but it looks like it needs only to be /certificates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could provide a little more detail on your routes as @mythz has asked that would be helpful.

In order to browse to `http://localhost:12543/api/certificates` I would create a request class like

```
[Route("/certificates")] //**this assumes you have a web.config with 'api' as custom path
public class Certificate
{
  public string FieldOne {get; set;}
}
```

You could also use the Fluent API described [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing)

**When I click on the operation it gives me available route for the operation "api/certificates"...But, if I do `http://localhost:12543/api/certificates` I get 404 error**

If you are seeing "GET api/certificates" on the `'json/metadata?op=Certificate'` page, it sounds like you are doing `[Route("/api/certificates")]`. Having 'api' in the route is unnecessary since the 'api' part of the path/url would already be configured in the web.config.

**It sounds like you have done this in the web.config - but for reference see [here](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/) under b) Host services at /custompath

```
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add path="api*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*"/>
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```